# tikzexternalize error

Tags: tikz-external

I get the error "`Paragraph ended before \tikzexternalize@opt was complete`" on the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node [draw,rectangle,minimum width=0.5cm,minimum height=0.5cm] {};

\begin{scope}[xshift=0.5cm]
\node [draw,rectangle,minimum width=0.5cm,minimum height=0.5cm] {2};
\end{scope}


\begin{scope}[xshift=1cm]
\node [draw,rectangle,minimum width=0.5cm,minimum height=0.5cm] {};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Any idea on how to fix this issue?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: It works fine for me. Have you tried putting `\tikzset{external/force remake}` in your preamble to force the regeneration of the image? If that doesn't help: What compiler are you using (`pdflatex`, `xelatex`)? What version of TikZ?

Comment: The date the version of the Latex I am using was built is january 2007.

Comment: I am using the University's computers. I guess I will have to try from my laptop at home later. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The earliest version of the `external` lib required users to provide the name of the main TeX file as first argument, i.e. something like `\tikzexternalize{maintexfile}`.

Considering that your TeX installation is from 2007, I would guess that this is the problem here.

Suggested solution: upgrade to a more recent version of TeX. In can be installed in home directories if needed.